# Are there holes in every neighbourhood in GL(n,R)?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, general-linear-group

$GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ can be seen as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ with points of non invertible matrix removed which form "holes" in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. These holes seems to be dense in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ which will mean any neighbourhood of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ will contain holes, even for the neighbourhood that is homeomorphic to some neighbourhood of the oringin of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. It is strange that a region with holes is homeomorphic to a region without holes.

Is this an example of a region with holes is homeomorphic to a region without holes, or is non invertible matrix not dense in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$?

Comment: Also a region with 'holes' cannot be homeomorphic to a region without 'holes'. Think about the fact that when $n=1$, removing a point disconnects the region.

Comment: It should be easy to see that there aren't any noninvertible matrices close to, say, $\pmatrix{10&0\cr0&10\cr}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. This is a consequence of the determinant map being continuous. Also tells you that the set of non invertible matrices cannot be dense. The invertible matrices on the other hand are.

Comment: It seems that for any invertible matrix, you can find another one that is near enough to the given one, is that right? Does this not imply dense?

Comment: The openness implies something further, that for every invertible matrix $A$ there is a $\delta$ such that all matrices $B$ satisfying $\|A-B\|<\delta$ are invertible. You can find a constructive proof of this from the fact that for a matrix $B$, $A-B=A(I-A^{-1}B)$. Can you see how taking B with norm sufficiently small makes $(I-A^{-1}B)$ invertible?

Comment: For a non invertible matrix $M$, for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, $M+\epsilon I$ is invertible.